# How to disable triggers in PostgreSQL 9?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

In PostgreSQl 8.x to disable triggers I do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE table DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

When I do this in PostgreSQL 9 I get the following:

```
my_database=> ALTER TABLE my_table DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_25366" is a system trigger
```

PS: This table was created by the user that is running this command.

Any clues on this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some triggers are added automatically to enforce constraints, and those can't be disabled unless you are a superuser. If you only want to disable the normal triggers which you have added then do this:

```
ALTER TABLE table DISABLE TRIGGER USER;
```

Comment: @André: This behavior was the same since pg **8.1**. (And don't forget to `ALTER TABLE table ENABLE TRIGGER USER;` afterwards, btw.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I only can disable if I do "TRIGGER ALL" with Postgres user, "TRIGGER USER" do not disable the Triggers.

Comment: Well it won't disable the constraint triggers no, because then your constraints won't be enforced. If you want to disable those then you will have to be a superuser.

Comment: To make someone a super user, run "ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER;" as a superuser.